# Spring Bean object marshaling depends on the order given in the XML?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a simple example program here:

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {



        try {
            FileSystemXmlApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("TestBeanFile.xml");
            Object o = context.getBean("AInstance");
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    private static class A implements InitializingBean {
        private B myB;

        public A() {
            System.out.println("A constructor");
        }

        public void setB(B aB) {
            myB = aB;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("A aps");
        }
    }

    private static class B implements Runnable, InitializingBean {
        private C myC;
        private volatile boolean exit = false;

        public B() {
            System.out.println("B constructor");
        }

        public void setC(C aC) {
            myC = aC;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("B aps");
            if (myC == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("C cannot be null");
            new Thread(this).start();           
        }

        public void exit() {
            exit = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!exit) {
                System.out.println(myC.getValue());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


    }

    private static class C implements InitializingBean {
        private String value = "C's value";

        public C() {
            System.out.println("C constructor");
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("C aps");
        }
    }

}
```

And here is a simple XML to bean load them which intentionally has an incorrect fully qualified name to the A class. This should mean that C B and A dont get constructed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream-2.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip-2.1.xsd">


    <bean id="CInstance" class = "com.test.Main.C" />

    <bean id="BInstance" class = "com.test.Main.B">
        <property name="C" ref="CInstance" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="AInstance" class = "com.test.Main.A1">
        <property name="B" ref="BInstance"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

When you run this application using the above XML C and B DO get constructed but A doesnt. It will produce the following output (omitting the stack trace when the exception is thrown, but I assure you A does not get constructed):

```
C constructor
C aps
B constructor
B aps
C's value
C's value
C's value
....... // one a second
```

If you modify the XML to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream-2.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip-2.1.xsd">

    <bean id="AInstance" class = "com.test.Main.A1">
        <property name="B" ref="BInstance"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="BInstance" class = "com.test.Main.B">
        <property name="C" ref="CInstance" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="CInstance" class = "com.test.Main.C" />
</beans>
```

The only output you get is the stack trace, and the B and C objects dont get constructed at all.

This seems like its a bug in spring. I dont understand why the marshaling of the objects, and the constructors / afterpropertiesSet methods which are run depend on the order of their appearance in the XML. What this means for me, is that when I have classes which construct threads in their constructors / after properties set methods, if I'm not careful about how I order the elements in the XML I can end up leaking resources if my only reference to them is, in this example, the A class. Because it fails construction in both cases.

So, is this a bug, or is this some feature that I dont understand? If this is a feature, what reason would they have to make the order of marshaling dependent on the XML file, instead of the object graph of the bean definitions?

Comment: Could it be because it is `com.test.Main.A1`, and not `com.test.Main.A`?

Comment: @MikeKobit Thats intentional. The example demostrates that none of these objects should get created because of the incorrect fully qualified name for the bean AInstance. yet, depending on how I order them, it is possible that spring will construct the B and C classes anyway, possibly leaking resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring first reads the `<bean>` and other elements in the XML configuration and creates appropriate `BeanDefinition` objects defining them.

It then has to initialize them. To do this, it has to decide on an order. The order of initialization is undefined, unless a bean depends on another or there is a mix of `@Order`, implementations of `Ordered` and a few others (depends on the case).

In your first example, `CInstance` is initialized first. Then `BInstance` is initialized. Part of its initialization involves invoking its `afterPropertiesSet()` method which launches a non-daemon thread. Then Spring attempts to initialize `AInstance` and fails.

In your second example, Spring attempts to initialize `AInstance` first. It fails immediately, with no change to start a second thread.

Note that in a declaration like

```
<bean id="AInstance" class="com.example.Spring.A1">
    <property name="B" ref="BInstance" />
</bean>
```

although `AInstance` depends on `BInstance`, the actual instance needs to be initialized before any property setters can be invoked to assign `BInstance` to `B`. So Spring begins the initialization of `AInstance` by instantiating the class. If it fails, the entirety of context refresh fails. If it passes, it will then initialize the `BInstance` bean and use it to set the `B` property.

Comment: I understand how I received the output I got, what doesnt make sense is that the dependency chain for the objects did not change, only the XML did. I order them one way, I dont leak resources, I order them the other, and I do. It seems to me that Spring should probably be checking at the very least that it can find the required type of the A class before constructing B. Same for B to C. But clearly it doesnt. IMHO, this pretty much eliminates Spring as an acceptable solution to serialization in the event classes have resources which need to be cleaned up.

Comment: @MarkW Let me get back to you. I'm pretty sure order is undefined. There may be tricks you can use.

Comment: I am investigating spring based solutions to this issue as well, possibly constructor vs property injection? Maybe others. I appreciate you looking deep though, thanks!

Comment: @MarkW You could have `<bean>` definitions with circular references. For example, `A` has a property `B` and `B` has a property `A`. Under some circumstances, that should be allowed. So how does Spring choose?

Comment: @MarkW There's also the fact that Spring needs to predict the type of your bean in order to check for some beans that need to be initialized before everything else, eg. `BeanPostProcessor`. So the `ClassNotFoundException` would happen before Spring could even go check for any dependencies in `<property>`. (It ~~~probably could figure something out, but it doesn't.) You should consider posting a feature request.

Comment: @MarkW For the reason above, constructor injection wouldn't help for this case.